# Parsing JSON in C# with very large JSON array

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to parse a big JSON array into a c# object. Now I know of the normal way where you take a class with matching keys to the JSON object and then assign each value of the JSON object to the matching key in the c# class. but this would be horribly inefficient for my purpose because im dealing with very large JSON objects here is an example:

```
    [{
  "storeId": "331",
  "storeName": "Bergen, Lagunen",
  "status": "Open",
  "address": {
    "street": "Laguneveien 1",
    "postalCode": "5239",
    "city": "Rådal",
    "gpsCoord": "60.297116;5.331159",
    "globalLocationNumber": "7080003251008",
    "organisationNumber": "888039902"
  },
  "telephone": "22 01 50 00",
  "email": "kundesenter@vinmonopolet.no",
  "category": "6",
  "openingHours": {
    "regularHours": [{
      "dayOfTheWeek": "Monday",
      "openingTime": "10:00",
      "closingTime": "18:00",
      "closed": false
    }, {
      "dayOfTheWeek": "Tuesday",
      "openingTime": "10:00",
      "closingTime": "18:00",
      "closed": false
    }, {
      "dayOfTheWeek": "Wednesday",
      "openingTime": "10:00",
      "closingTime": "18:00",
      "closed": false
    }, {
      "dayOfTheWeek": "Thursday",
      "openingTime": "10:00",
      "closingTime": "18:00",
      "closed": false
    }, {
      "dayOfTheWeek": "Friday",
      "openingTime": "10:00",
      "closingTime": "18:00",
      "closed": false
    }, {
      "dayOfTheWeek": "Saturday",
      "openingTime": "10:00",
      "closingTime": "15:00",
      "closed": false
    }, {
      "dayOfTheWeek": "Sunday",
      "openingTime": "",
      "closingTime": "",
      "closed": true
    }],
    "exceptionHours": [{
      "date": "2020-05-21",
      "openingTime": "",
      "closingTime": "",
      "message": "Stengt Kristi himmelfartsdag"
    }]
  },
  "lastChanged": {
    "date": "2020-05-04",
    "time": "00:02:04"
  }
}]
```

is there any way to dynamically make this into a c# object as you can in javascript using JSON.parse?

Comment: Check out Newtonsoft.Json and in particular the [JArray.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm) method.

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't create a class matching your object. It doesn't seem exceptionally large to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have big json. I will assume that you say that because the json have many properties you don't need. If you *do* need all properties, I would just define a class containing all the properties.

That said. I think you have two real options if we'd go for Newtonsoft.Json.

### 1. Define a class with only the properties you need

```
public class Pruned
{
    public string StoreId { get; set; }
}

var prunedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Pruned>>(myJsonString);
```

### 2. Deserialize into a JArray and treat it as a dynamic object.

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse(myJsonString);
var firstStoreId = jArray[0]["storeId"];
```